# Cannot write to s3 from aws glue (attribute error)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to write to a csv file in a folder in s3. Simple enough right?

Here is a snippet of my code with a simple map.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def combineNames(rec):
    rec["Name"] = {}
    rec["Name"]["First"] = rec["first"]
    rec["Name"]["Last"] = rec["last"]
    del rec["first"]
    del rec["last"]
    return rec


glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
bucket_name = "my-bucket-name"
database = "my-database"
output_path = "s3://{}/outputs/output.csv".format(bucket_name)
print("Data schema before maps")
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
       database = database,
       table_name = "my_table_name")
new =  Map.apply(frame = df, f = combineNames)
new.write.csv(path=output_path, mode='append', compression='gzip',sep='|', header='true')
```

However, when I run this job, I get an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'csv'`

I was under the impression for PySpark 2 and above, I can just do `df.write.csv`, as opposed to the previous way which was `df.write.format`.

I am using Python 3 and PySpark 2.4 if that helps.

Comment: I suspect that your `Map.apply` command is doing something different to what you expect.  What happens if you substitute `new` in the final line for `df` to make it `df.write.csv(path=output_path, mode='append', compression='gzip',sep='|', header='true')`.  I suspect this will work?

Comment: I tried that too and it also gave me the same error

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but I can confirm I have a bunch of AWS Glue code which has `df.write.csv()` and works fine...

Comment: I finally got it working. I followed the aws documentation and used `df.write(connection_type="s3",connection_options={"path":output_path},format="csv")`. I am using Python 3, Spark 2.4 for my job. I did notice however that in the outputfile, it included a bunch of blank columns labeled col4,col5...col89 when in reality my data scheme only had 3 columns (Name, Age, Sex). Is this working as intended??

Comment: How can you add struct to CSV? your `combineNames()` is creating Struct type. Can you try changing `format="csv"` to `format="json"`

Answer (score 0):

Another way I think in which it will work is -

```
#Dynamic Frame
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
   database = database,
   table_name = "my_table_name") 

#Make it DataFrame
df = df.toDF().coalesce(1) 

new =  Map.apply(frame = df, f = combineNames)
new.write.csv(path=output_path, mode='append', compression='gzip',sep='|', header='true')
```

Similarly if we want to go from DataFrame to DynamicFrame -

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
DyF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "DyF")
```